# Adding custom methods to Java BooleanProperty class

Tags: java, javafx

I like using Property classes, but I'm not a fan of how long of a sentence is needed to do simple things.

I wanted to extend the SimpleBooleanProperty class so that instead of needing to do something like this:

```
myProperty.setValue(!myProperty.getValue());
```

I could just do this:

```
myProperty.flip();
```

SO, I tried to extend the SimpleBooleanClass, but it does not work.

Here is my attempt at doing this with relevant results posted below:

```
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class CBP extends SimpleBooleanProperty {
    @Override public void bind(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable) {}
    @Override public void unbind() {}
    @Override public boolean isBound() {return false;}
    @Override public Object getBean() {return null;}
    @Override public String getName() {return null;}
    @Override public boolean get() {return false;}
    @Override public void set(boolean value) {}
    @Override public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super Boolean> listener) {}
    @Override public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super Boolean> listener) {}
    @Override public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {}
    @Override public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {}

    public void flip(){
        super.setValue(!super.getValue());
    }
}
```

This attept to use it produced the output as shown:

```
CBP cbp = new CBP();
cbp.setValue(true);
if (cbp.getValue().equals(true)) System.out.println("TRUE"); else System.out.println("FALSE");
cbp.flip();
if (cbp.getValue().equals(true)) System.out.println("TRUE"); else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

This is the output:

```
FALSE
FALSE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it ok when your get() method always returns false?

Comment: Pardon me if I am stating the obvious, but did you try debugging your code and stepping into methods `setValue()` and `getValue()` to see what they actually do? Class `SimpleBooleanProperty` derives from `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty`. I'm only guessing but maybe that means that you can't change its value?

Answer (score 2):

The `setValue()` method expects a wrapped Boolean object. Under the hood, it uses `get()` to unwrap the value. So when you use `setValue(true)`, your primitive is being auto-boxed into a Boolean object with the value `true`. Then, `SimpleBooleanProperty` uses `.get()` to unwrap the object into a primitive. You have `get()` overridden to always return false.

If you step through your program, you'll see that when `setValue(true)` is executed, the value is actually set as `false` because of this.

Answer (score -2):

Based on what @scgrk posted as his answer, I simply changed these @overrides and everything is now working as intended. My IDE auto-filled those overrides, and I thought I had looked at them carefully, but I was mistaken.

Thank you scgrk for pointing me in the right direction.

```
@Override public void unbind     ()      {super.unbind();}
@Override public boolean isBound ()      {return super.isBound();}
@Override public Object getBean  ()      {return super.getBean();}
@Override public String getName  ()      {return super.getName();}
@Override public boolean get     ()      {return super.get();}
@Override public void set(boolean value) {super.set(value);}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just not override those methods? I'm sure there is a reason, but can't think of it right now.

Comment: @NomadMaker - Thank you for this question, as it made me think back to how I got there ... so how it happened was that I originally extended BooleanProperty for this class, and IntelliJ Idea told me that I needed to include all of those overrides. However, when I tried to use the class, I realized that my BooleanProperty declarations were set to new instances of SimpleBooleanProperty so I then changed the extension of the class over to SimpleBooleanProperty and assumed I needed to leave those overrides in place. I now see that was an error on my part.  Thank you again!

Comment: this answer is so wrong/useless (sry for being blunt ...) that you should consider deleting it: don't write code that's not required, ever! Doesn't matter how it evolved, at the end of the day it must be cleaned - meaning here to remove all those overrides that do nothing but delegate to super. If you do, it's a no-op answer (and question ;) - which happens, but isn't overly helpful to others.

Comment: @kleopatra - I tried to delete the question, but the site won't let me.